# URL type column issue in SharePoint List

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePiont Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have a list on a page, and one column in the list is URL type. Currently, when I click the link, the URL pointed destination page will be opened in current browser windows. How to make the page pointed by the URL open in a new browser window?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Does this seem to be on topic?

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/SharepointLinksListOpenInNewWindow.aspx

Comment: Looks cool, thanks! Any easier solutions?